# ClassNotFoundException org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I done everything i could to solve this by my own, searched all over the internet and nothing helped since then. I am building a web application using java/spring/hibernate/tomcat and, at the session filter in the web.xml, i am getting this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:120)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4659)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5281)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Really do not know what to do to fix this, look at my config files:

My pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>br.com.mobcube</groupId>
<artifactId>amigooculto</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Amigo Oculto Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.10.Final</hibernate.version>
    <jersey.version>2.18</jersey.version>
</properties>
```

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- MySQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.35</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Jersey -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Google-GSON -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jersey-Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>2.18</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jersey Upload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Commons-IO -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

```
<build>
    <finalName>amigo</finalName>

    <plugins>
    <!-- Compiler -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>    
</build>
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

```
<display-name>Amigo</display-name>
<!-- OpenSessionInViewFilter pattern -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>sessionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sessionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>br.com.mobcube.rest.AmigoOcultoApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

And my applicationContext:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">
<!-- Scan do pacote para processar annotations -->
<context:component-scan base-package="br.com.mobcube">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation"
        expression="org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect" />
</context:component-scan>
<!-- conexao.properties -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:conexao.properties" />
</bean>
<!-- SessionFactory do Hibernate -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="br.com.mobcube.domain" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">${hibernate.use_sql_comments}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="namingStrategy">
        <bean class="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
    </property>
</bean>
<!-- Data Source do banco de dados -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver_class}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>
<!-- Hibernate = Transaction Manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
<!-- Transacao com @Transaction -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<!-- @Autowire -->
<context:annotation-config />
<!-- Spring AOP AspectJ -->
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
```

Any tips?

Comment: Why are you using jersey-spring3 with so many excludes together with spring4? You're asking for trouble there IMO.

Comment: Just doing just like a book i am following to learn. Can you suggest a better jersey configuration?

Comment: artifact versions are obsolete the moment the book hits print. You should probably just grab the latest Jersey, look it up on their website.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, i will look for it, but i just recreated my server and clean up my project and now, everything works fine!

Answer (score 0):

What i did was just recreate my server and clean my project: everything works fine now. I should be some eclipse bug/issue.